# Array reverse behavior in different browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

Run the following in the console of Firefox:
`Array.reverse([0,1]);`

Result: `[1,0]`

Run it again in Chrome:

`Array.reverse is not a function`

The whole point of me trying this was that I wanted to reverse an array into a copy of itself so that it would not change the original. My question: which browser has the correct behavior?

Seems to me that, [since reverse() is supposed to be on Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), Firefox is wrong. However, Firefox's behavior is more useful. So is this a Firefox bug?

Comment: This is the proper way `[0,1].reverse()`, the docs don't even show the way that you are using it, so I don't know why it works in firefox.

Comment: I don't know that I would classify implementing extra functionality as a bug.... (A failure to provide complete documentation, maybe). Reverse on Array.prototype in Firefox also works.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox introduced years ago [Array's generics method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods), in JS 1.6, but as mentioned in the linked page:

> "These are not part of ECMAScript standards and they are not supported
>   by non-Gecko browsers."

And:

> Array generics are non-standard, deprecated and will get removed in the near future.

Therefore you should avoid them.

More important, it doesn't solve your issue. You said that you want to avoid to change the original, but `Array.reverse(arr)` is equivalent to `arr.reverse()`, so you mutate anyway the original array.

If you want to avoid that, you should create a copy of it. If you just need a shallow copy, you can do:

```
let arr = [0, 1];
let reversed = [...arr].reverse();

console.log(arr, reversed); // [0, 1], [1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.reverse` is not a static method in Chrome (and some other browsers, e.g. Safari). You should do it like this:

```js
console.log([0, 1].reverse());
```

Comment: It is in Firefox. (There's also a `reverse()` on the prototype.)

Comment: Edited answer @Pointy